# Modify AIRPLANE_MODE_ON on Android 4.2 (and above)

Tags: android, sdk, settings

Since the sdk version 4.2 it seems like it's no longer possible to modify airplane-mode on devices since google has moved this setting to Settings.Global which is read-only.

Has anyone been able to bypass this without and kind of rooting?

My apps primary function is to enable airplane-mode when the screen is turned off, and this stopped working since 4.2.

Just want to double check that my assessment is correct and that my app is dead starting from android 4.2 and above.

References:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON

Comment: Are there any updates on this? Were you able to make it work on v4.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you explicitly ask for a solution without rooting, but if you have a rooted device there is at least the (kind of) official solution to move your app into folder `/system/app`. Then it is possible to write into `Settings.Global`:

```
Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, mode ? 1 : 0);
```

Have a look of how to [toggle airplane mode for 4.2](https://bitbucket.org/jholetzeck/ministatus-android/src/2f66bc57b4ca7a4f46181b05be47d91ca5456e9a/src/de/holetzeck/ministatus/AirplaneMode_SDK17.java?at=default)
and how to move your app into `/system/app` [here](https://bitbucket.org/jholetzeck/ministatus-android/src/2f66bc57b4ca7a4f46181b05be47d91ca5456e9a/src/de/holetzeck/ministatus/MiniStatusSettings.java?at=default). I use this for my toggle widget *Mini Status* ([source code link](https://bitbucket.org/jholetzeck/ministatus-android)).

Comment: can you share more detailed steps to follow airplane mode settings writing on rooted devices. where do I start my initial step.

Answer (score 6):

> Just want to double check that my assessment is correct and that my app is dead starting from android 4.2 and above.

Yes. Or, to put it another way, if there is a back-door way to modify this setting, it represents a security hole, which will eventually get closed, much like the enable/disable GPS restriction that has existed for 3+ years.

Comment: I was looking for another official way to do this rather than the old way, not any back doors. That's why I explicitly wrote "without any kind of rooting". 

Because I cannot understand why Google would limit access to such a trivial feature like airplane mode. I mean, what harm can it do? 

My nexus 7 just went from 6-8 days standby to about 2. Thanks a million Google. 

And yes, I am biased since I wrote an app to achieve just that (airlockapp.com), but why limit access to a perfectly safe feature?

Comment: @Tommie: "I was looking for another official way to do this rather than the old way, not any back doors" -- by definition, there isn't, at least at present. They would not have moved it to `Settings.Global` otherwise. "I mean, what harm can it do?" -- you mean, besides disconnect the person from the outside world, possibly without their consent or knowledge? Heck, I *use* an airplane mode app widget, and I have always considered the decision to leave that setting in `Settings.System` to be a dumb move. I'd've probably let it be modified via a dedicated permission, though.

Comment: I agree that a dedicated setting would be sufficient. Removing the possibility to control airplane-mode on android-device seems harsh.

Comment: dedicated setting = dedicated permission. Don't walk and type kids! :)