# Android Disable airplane mode at version >=4.1

Tags: android

I need to disable airplane mode in my kiosk app, i tried snippet below to overwrite device settings

```
try {
    int airplane = Settings.System.getInt(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_on");
    if (airplane == 1) {
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE").putExtra("state", false));
    }
} catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code seems to work up to android version 4.0, whereas in 4.1 and above it doesn't works.I hope to make it work by rooting the device to access the system settings.
Actually my task to disable airplane mode feature from status bar in nexus tablet. Let me know any suggestions on these to implement.

Comment: @JeanHominal, Yes..it always need to be in disable state.Once the user enable the Airplane from status bar tray it need to be in diable state. As like the Surelock app available in google play store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android <= 4.1:

```
static boolean getAirplaneMode(Context context)
{
   return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
}


static void setAirplaneMode(Context context, boolean mode)
{
   if (mode != getAirplaneMode(context))
   {
      Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, mode ? 1 : 0);
      Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
      newIntent.putExtra("state", mode);
       context.sendBroadcast(newIntent);
    }
}
```

For Android 4.2 have a look at [Modify AIRPLANE_MODE_ON on Android 4.2 (and above)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422527/modify-airplane-mode-on-on-android-4-2-and-above/15448650#15448650)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,i tried the same on 4.1 and below it works perfect. but on 4.2 it doesn't works. I think we may need to root the device first to access system level settings.Is't possible to do without rooting the 4.2 device.

Comment: For 4.2 please follow the link and read my answer there how to solve for rooted 4.2 device. You may accept my answer then.

Comment: only the rooted device allows to change the device settings on version 4.2+, is it right?

Comment: The point is that the app needs the privilege to write `Settings.Global` on 4.2.This can be done by copying the app into folder `/system/app` and this part needs a rooted device. A rooted device alone is not enough!

Comment: @j.holrtzeck, I have successfully achieved the airplane mode disable on android version 4.2 and below these version.I'm facing a problem in android version 4.3 even the app moves to system app, while trying to toggle airplane mode the above code throws an exception as "permission denied". I need your suggestion to fix these problem.