# android - Settings.Global#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON - Field requires API level 17 (current min is 16)

Tags: android

I am getting the following warning :

Field requires API level 17 (current min is 16): android.provider.Settings.Global#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON  TrainingListActivity.java   /Swimmer/src/com/swimtechtest/swimmer   line 89 Android Lint Problem

which is right , as I have in my manifest.xml

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I am testing on both Android 4.1.2 (JellyBean)  and Android 4.4.2 (KitKat) ...

AIRPLANE_MODE_ON  is well tested on 4.4.2 but not on the 4.1.2... 
how should I modifiy my current test code to be used with both versions ?

```
            ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        Boolean airplaneMode =  Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        if (!airplaneMode) {
            SwimmerApp.displayAlertDialog("You are not connected to internet", TrainingListActivity.this);
        } else {
            SwimmerApp.displayAlertDialog("Please set airplane mode to OFF", TrainingListActivity.this);            
        }
```

thanks for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON` was only introduced in API level 17, while your app is configured to run on API level 16 or newer.

Edit your AndroidManifest.xml and set the `minSdkVersion` to 17.

Comment: In this case my app will not run on 4.1.2 ...  I guess their is a way to test the version and test airplane mode in lower versions ..

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Check out `getAirplaneMode()` in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919346/android-disable-airplane-mode-at-version-4-1

Comment: I found  a way to test it  in both versions .. airplaneMode =  Settings.System.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), "airplane_mode_on", 0) != 0;

Comment: your answer and my comment just Xed ... thanks a lot yur were right... I vote for your answer ..;

Comment: I believe the right thing to do would be to programmatically check the version that the app is running on, no?