# Airplane mode toggle in Android 4.3

Tags: android

I'm facing a problem in android version 4.3 to control airplane mode by code.For this I converted the user app into system  using system/ app mover application available in google play.Once the user enables the airplane mode, the background service have the control to check the airplane mode and reset it to off state and send the broadcast changes to the device.Below the snippet I implemented in my code to keep the airplane mode state in off.But it fails in android version 4.3. It throws an exception called "permission denied". Let me know is these any additional permission need to added in manifest or else let me know your suggestions on these issue to fixed.

```
try {
                    Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                            "airplane_mode_on", 0);
                    isAirplaneModeOn = isAirplaneModeOn(context);
                    Intent localIntent2 = new Intent(
                            "android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");
                    localIntent2.putExtra("state", isAirplaneModeOn);
                    context.sendBroadcast(localIntent2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("TAG",
                            e.toString() + "\n" + e.getMessage());
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving an App into the /system/app folder does *not* turn it into a System App - it simply makes the App uninstallable because /system is normally mounted read-only.

What you are trying to do requires full System App privileges. You can only get these by signing your app with the same key used to sign the original firmware Apps - the platform key. In other words, you need access to whoever built the version of Android you are running on and get them to sign your APK.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot do it starting from Android 4.2. Because that settings was relocated here from either Settings.System or Settings.Secure. But on previous vesions it works fine.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html

> If your app is currently making changes to settings previously defined
>   in Settings.System (such as AIRPLANE_MODE_ON), then you should expect
>   that doing so will no longer work on a device running Android 4.2 or
>   higher if those settings were moved to Settings.Global.

Related question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422527/modify-airplane-mode-on-on-android-4-2-and-above)